# При отправлении ответа клиенту часть сообщения теряется. Ошибка с сервером на Python

Tags: python, сервер, клиент-сервер

Приветстсвую! Пишу сервер, который должен отправлять XML в ответ на запросы. Возникла проблема при отправке ответа клиенту. Текст сообщения почему-то обрезается. К примеру, XML содержит `40975` символов, но при попытке отправить их клиенту, клиенту дозодит лишь часть символов (`2458`). Возможно я использую ненадёжное соединение? Я наследуюсь свой класс обработчик: `class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler)`. Отправляю запрос, предварительно прочитав его из файла:

```
with open(FILENAME_ANSWER, 'w+') as f:                
    answer = f.read()
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header("Content-length", len(answer))
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(answer)
self.wfile.close()
```

Выглядит это следующи образом:

На запуск скрипта `curl.sh` мне приходит обрезанный текст XML (причём с двух сторон!). В чём может быть причина? Всё дело в длинном файле(более 1700 строк) или в чём то ещё?
Вот скриншоты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтоб помочь вам нужен будет код вашего сервера

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду код ответа сервера? Когда перед тем как отправить ответ (`self.wfile.write(answer)`) я отправляю код ответа `self.send_response(200)`.

Answer (score 0):

Понял в чём была причина ошибки. Как говорил Дональд Кнут: "Преждевременная оптимизация — корень всех зол." В моём случае я пытался в одном блоке контекстного менеджера with и записать XML в файл и тут же его считать:

```
with open(FILENAME_ANSWER, 'w+') as f:
        tree.write(f, encoding=ENCODING)
        answer = f.read()
```

Понятное дело, что результат `answer` в этом случае - не определённый. Решил я эту проблему разделив запись и чтение на два разных блока `with`:

```
with open(FILENAME_ANSWER, 'w') as f:
    tree.write(f, encoding=ENCODING)
with open(FILENAME_ANSWER, 'r') as f:
    answer = f.read()
```

Итог - корректно записанный XML, корректно считанный, а следовательно и отправленный клиенту.